# TreeView в WPF: как добавить родительский а потом дочерний узел?

Tags: wpf, c#

Есть вот такое

```
<TreeView Height="414" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-6,-2,0,0" Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Padding="0">
</TreeView>
```

Задача в том, чтобы добавить узел **Drinks** а к нему дочернии узлы **1 2 3 4**
Т.е., чтобы получилось примерно так:

```
<TreeView Height="414" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-6,-2,0,0" Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Padding="0">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Drinks">
        <TreeViewItem Header="1"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="2"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="3"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="4"></TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Как реализовать это программно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TreeViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.aspx) это наследний [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), у него есть свойство [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items.aspx), в которое ты можешь добавлять элементы. Все остальное - внешний цикл для добавления родительских элементов, под каждый родительский - свой подцикл для дочерних узлов. Хотя это и не best practice, но ответ на твой вопрос.

По феншую - это реализовать привязку к каким-то данным (к [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) или коллекции-свойству из [ViewModel, по этой ссылке как раз пример с TreeView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx)) и использовать [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx), для определения вида элементов в дереве.

Comment: Т.е. как я понимаю, можно привязать к  CollectionViewSource, и в дальнейшем работать с CollectionViewSource ?

Comment: Да, все верно.

Comment: А можно где нибудь пример посмотреть?

Comment: Можно, по ссылкам в ответе.